# Can't bind model to Controller, MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 Views and 1 EditorTemplate

The first view is the Cart.cshtml view and this view has a Model (CartModel)
Inside of this view there is a call to the second view using:

```
@Html.Partial("OrderSummary", Model.CartSummaryModel)
```

Inside of the OrderSummary.cshtml view I have this

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OrderItems)
```

And inside the EditorTemplate (called OrderItemModel) I have

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedQuantity, Model.QuantityList)
```

The problem is when causing a post on the top most view (Cart.cshtml) the model isn't binding in the controller the "CartSummaryModel" is null. When swapping to a FormCollection there are 2 keys which are:

```
OrderItems[0].SelectedQuantity
OrderItems[1].SelectedQuantity
```

How do I bind the form collection data to the Controller's action method?

Comment: try replacing `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedQuantity, Model.QuantityList)` with `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedQuantity, Model.QuantityList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the partial:

```
@Html.Partial("OrderSummary", Model.CartSummaryModel)
```

Here you are *loosing* the `CartSummaryModel` prefix that is required in your input field names. So instead of using partials use editor templates.

Go ahead and move this `OrderSummary.cshtml` to `EditorTemplates/OrderSummary.cshtml` and then inside your view replace:

```
@Html.Partial("OrderSummary", Model.CartSummaryModel)
```

with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CartSummaryModel, "OrderSummary")
```

and if the type of the `CartSummaryModel` property is `OrderSummary` you don't even need to specify the name of the editor template as ASP.NET MVC will find it by convention:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CartSummaryModel)
```

Now you are good to go and you will see the correct keys sent to the server:

```
CartSummaryModel.OrderItems[0].SelectedQuantity
CartSummaryModel.OrderItems[1].SelectedQuantity
```